# MVC4 Simple Membership with custom database and database first issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am implementing Membership and security in my MVC4 website using custom database. Every things working fine but when I used .EDMX(Designer) to add my database tables membership and security starts giving errors. **I also know the reason: This is due to duplicate Class files as default membership use code first approach and I am using database first approach.** My question is there is any soluton that I can work using database first(EDMX) and also my security and membership functionality works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: This might be a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112214/using-mvc-4-simplemembership-with-an-existing-database-first-ef-model/15234074#15234074

Comment: Thanks Alistair Findlay .... I have already solved my problem. Thanks for your efforts. Tried whole day with different solutions and finally solved my problem.I have also used the same way as your post states.

Comment: Nice one - I'll add a proper reply so you can accept as an answer and close off the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following post details the steps to take when using SimpleMembership with a Database-First  approach: [Using MVC 4 SimpleMembership with an existing database-first EF model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112214/using-mvc-4-simplemembership-with-an-existing-database-first-ef-model/15234074#15234074)

Also, you may find the following link has some useful information about SimpleMembership: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx