# Will SimpleMembership work in an MVC3 DB first app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, simplemembership

Building an MVC 3 app to work with an existing SQL Server 2012 database.  The existing database has an existing UserProfile table with id, login, password and email.

I used [this](http://anderly.com/2011/08/11/using-simplemembership-in-mvc3/) quick tutorial to get the nuget simplemembership pack working, and modified it to connect to my existing db and userprofile table.  I received an error:

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider
```

it is pointing to this line in the SimpleMembershipMvc3.cs file:

```
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(connectionStringName: "MyEntities", userTableName: "UserAccount", userIdColumn: "UserId", userNameColumn: "Login", autoCreateTables: false);
```

Apparently it is possible to get simplemembership working in an MVC3 DB First scenario, but all the articles I find online are either CodeFirst, or MVC4. I am looking for a complete tutorial for MVC3 DB First.

And I am not tied to SimpleMembership, I will try anything as long as it works.  I tried making a custom SQLMembership Provider but could not get it to stop building its own, seperate database.

The only functionality I need to have is register, logon/off (all of which I already had, before I found out about the existence on membership and authentication), and I need to secure the members only pages of the site, which is why I started looking into all this in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following link which is specific to database first model of EF:

[Using MVC 4 SimpleMembership with an existing database-first EF model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112214/using-mvc-4-simplemembership-with-an-existing-database-first-ef-model)

While it's specific to MVC4, it should be pretty similar to MVC3, and if not, then use the following two resources.  The first one helps set up SimpleMembership with MVC3:

http://anderly.com/2011/08/11/using-simplemembership-in-mvc3/

This second link, just explains how to upgrade to MVC4 as another alternative to follow, and then reference the very first hyperlink I provided at the top.

http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806